# How should we pass cart details to amazon checkout?

Tags: php, zend-framework, amazon-s3

I am trying to create a basic implementation of amazon checkout. This code has been taken from my controller.

```
public function amazAction()
{
    // Key from Amazon
    $merchant_id = 'xxxxx';
    $aws_access_key_id = 'xxxxx'; 
    $aws_secret_access_key = 'xxxxx';

    // Set up cart
    $form['aws_access_key_id'] = $aws_access_key_id;
    $form['currency_code'] = 'USD';
    $form['item_merchant_id_1'] = $merchant_id;
    $form['item_price_1'] = 10;
    $form['item_quantity_1'] = 1;
    $form['item_sku_1'] = 11;
    $form['item_title_1'] = test;
    ksort($form);

    // Encode order as string and calculate signature
    $order = '';
    foreach ($form as $key => $value) {
        $order .= $key . "=" . rawurlencode($value) . "&";
    }
    $form['merchant_signature'] = base64_encode(hash_hmac('sha1', $order, $aws_secret_access_key, true));

    // Return string with Amazon javascript and HTML form
    // Assumes you already have jQuery loaded elsewhere on page
    // URL's link to live site, not sandbox!
    $this->view->amazon_order_html = '<script type="text/javascript" src="https://images-na.ssl-images-amazon.com/images/G/01/cba/js/widget/widget.js"></script>
    <form target="_blank" method="post" action="https://payments-sandbox.amazon.com/checkout/' . $merchant_id . '">';
    foreach ( $form as $key => $value ) {   
        $this->view->amazon_order_html .= '<input type="hidden" name="' . $key . '" value="' . $value . '" />';
    }
    $this->view->amazon_order_html .= '<input alt="Checkout with Amazon Payments" src="https://payments-sandbox.amazon.com/gp/cba/button?ie=UTF8&color=orange&background=white&cartOwnerId=' . $merchant_id . '&size=large" type="image"></form>';
}
```

when i ran this page, i got the following error from amazon

> We're sorry, but there's a problem with this order. Please contact the
>   merchant directly for assistance in completing this order.

How can I fix this error? Also I need to know how can I pass the amount for discount price, shipping name and shipping rate in hidden fields?

Kindly advice on this

Answer (score 1):

For shipping, try adding something that will output the following:

```
<input type="hidden" name="shipping_method_price_per_shipment_amount_1" value="0.00" />
<input type="hidden" name="shipping_method_price_per_unit_rate_1" value="0.00" />
<input type="hidden" name="shipping_method_price_type_1" value="weight_based" />
<input type="hidden" name="shipping_method_region_1" value="world_all" />
<input type="hidden" name="shipping_method_service_level_1" value="standard" />
```

Based on your code you should be able to add something like (alter as needed):

```
$form['shipping_method_price_per_shipment_amount_1'] = 0.00;
$form['shipping_method_price_per_unit_rate_1'] = 0.00;
$form['shipping_method_price_type_1'] = 'weight_based';
$form['shipping_method_region_1'] = 'world_all';
$form['shipping_method_service_level_1'] = 'standard';
```

I hope that works for you...